# browser-sync does not update the ngModel

Tags: angularjs, angular, single-page-application, angular-ngmodel, browser-sync

I am using [browser-sync](https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync) in a SPA built with AngularJS and Angular 5. 
I configured `browser-sync` like this:

```
codeSync: true,
ghostMode: {
    scroll: true,
    clicks: true,
    forms: true
}
```

The form is submitted in all the browsers.
NgModel is updated only in the browser I am actively using, not in the synchronised browsers. The input is filled up, but nothing more (e.g. I still see the class ng-empty instead of ng-dirty).
What should I do to mirror all the changes in the synchronised browsers too?